# Only Wanting Unique Words in my output file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I am trying to write some code that takes an input file which is a paragraph of text(this paragraph has duplicates of certain words), I then want to write this text to an output file, however I do not want the duplicates of the words written to my output file, just unique words, this includes one copy of the duplicates.

This is as far as I have gotten, I can't seem to figure out how to write only unique words.

```
def unique_file(input_filename, output_filename):

    input_file = open(input_filename,'r')
    content = input_file.read()
    input_file.close()
    word_list = content.split()
    output_file = open(output_filename,'w')

    unique_list = []
        for words in word_list:
            if words not in unique_list:
                output_file.write(words + '\n')
                output_file.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `set`:

```
def unique_file(input_filename, output_filename):

    input_file = open(input_filename,'r')
    content = input_file.read()
    input_file.close()
    word_list = content.split()
    output_file = open(output_filename,'w')

    word_list = list(set(word_list))

    for word in word_list:
        output_file.write(words + '\n')
    output_file.close
```

---

---

If you want to use `not in`, do:

word_list is your list of words **with** duplicates

```
unique_list = []
for word in word_list:
    if word not in unique_list:
        unique_list.append(word)
        output_file.write(word + '\n')
output_file.close()
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this using 'not in' ?

Comment: I have adjusted my code and I don't receive any data being written into my output file?

Comment: @MrWallace, Yes that was simply a way to get a unique list, to write to the file, you need to use `write`

Comment: @MrWallace, Note: the close command should be outside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
word_list = [word.lower() for word in word_list]
```

and then:

```
list(set(word_list))
```

will give you a list of unique words. Python's [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) will automatically get rid of duplicates. The reason for doing a `.lower()` is to treat `Ball` and `ball` as same words and have just one of those. Get rid of the first line if you wanna treat them to be two words.